# wxPython dynamcally created buttons overlap

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I'm using wx to create a simple GUI (or so I thought) in python with enthought canopy (version 1.5.5, python 2.7). This is the code of the program: 
`

```
import wx
import sqlite3
import webbrowser
import wx.lib.inspection

class database():
    def __init__(self):
        self.db = sqlite3.connect("MarkIt")
        self.cursor = self.db.cursor()

    def execute(self, query):
        #fetching data resulted from a query
        self.cursor.execute(query)
        return self.cursor.fetchall()

    def delete(self, lst):
        for i in range(lst):
            self.cursor.execute("delete from bookmarks where name=?", lst[i])

    def edit(self, lst):
        self.cursor.execute("update bookmarks set name=?, link=?, category=? where id=?",(lst[1],lst[2],lst[3],lst[0],))

    def filter(self):
        return

    def sort(self):
        return

    def add(self):
        return

    def close(self):
        self.db.close()
########################################################################
class RandomPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)



########################################################################
class window(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        #Main window layout
        super(window, self).__init__(parent, title = title,size = (800,600))
        self.dbase = database()
        self.toolbar()
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.create_main_panel()
        #self.divider()

        self.Show()
#++++++++++TOOLBAR+++++++++#         
    def toolbar(self):
        #Creating the toolbar
        tb = self.CreateToolBar()
        delete = tb.AddLabelTool(wx.ID_ANY, 'Delete', wx.Bitmap('icons/Delete-48.png'))
        edit = tb.AddLabelTool(wx.ID_ANY, 'Edit', wx.Bitmap('icons/edit.png'))
        filtertool = tb.AddLabelTool(wx.ID_ANY, 'Filter', wx.Bitmap('icons/filter.png'))
        sort = tb.AddLabelTool(wx.ID_ANY, 'Sort', wx.Bitmap('icons/sort.png'))
        add = tb.AddLabelTool(wx.ID_ANY, 'Add', wx.Bitmap('icons/add.png'))
        tb.Realize()

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TOOL, self.OnDelete, delete)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TOOL, self.OnEdit, edit)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TOOL, self.OnFilter, filtertool)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TOOL, self.OnSort, sort)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TOOL, self.OnAdd, add)

#TOOLBAR FUNCTIONS#       
    def OnDelete(self, event):
        return

    def OnEdit(self, event):
        return

    def OnFilter(self, event):
        return

    def OnSort(self, event):
        return

    def OnAdd(self, event):
        return
#--------------------------#
#++++++++++SCREEN DIVIDER++++++++++#
    def create_main_panel(self):      
        #Splitting remaining screen (left -> categories; right -> members of selected categories)
        mainbox = wx.SplitterWindow(self)
        leftpanel = RandomPanel(mainbox)
        rightpanel = RandomPanel(mainbox)
        query = """SELECT * FROM categories"""
        data = self.dbase.execute(query)

        wx.lib.inspection.InspectionTool().Show()
        categories = wx.ListBox(leftpanel, -1, size=(-1,-1), choices = [row[1] for row in data])
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LISTBOX, lambda event: self.onListBox(event, rightpanel), categories)
        #self.onBox("Recipes", rightpanel)

        mainbox.SplitVertically(leftpanel, rightpanel)
        mainbox.SetSashGravity(0.12)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(mainbox, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        #self.panel.SetSizer(mainbox)
######---TEST FUNCTION---########
    def onBox(self, category, parent):
        query = "SELECT book_name, link FROM bookmarks WHERE category=\'"+category+"\'"
        data = self.dbase.execute(query) 
        #book_name = name of the bookmarks; link = eventual link of bookmark
        i=0
        vbox2=wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        print('a')
        for row in data:
            #row[0] = book_name
            #row[1] = link
            #linebox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
            btn = wx.Button(parent,-1,label=row[0]) 
            #self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,lambda event:self.onClick(event, row[1]), btn)
            #self.mainbox.Add(btn)
            vbox2.Add(btn,1,wx.ALIGN_LEFT, 20) 
            #self.SetSizer(linebox)
            #self.vbox2.Add(linebox, 1, wx.CENTER)
            i+=1
        parent.SetSizer(vbox2)
##################################
    def onListBox(self, event, parent):
        category = event.GetEventObject().GetStringSelection() 
        query = "SELECT book_name, link FROM bookmarks WHERE category=\'"+category+"\'"
        data = self.dbase.execute(query) 
        #book_name = name of the bookmarks; link = eventual link of bookmark
        i=0
        vbox2=wx.GridBagSizer()
        btn=[]
        linebox=[]
        print('a')
        for row in data:
            #row[0] = book_name
            #row[1] = link
            btn.append(wx.Button(parent,-1,label=row[0]))
            #self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,lambda event:self.onClick(event, row[1]), btn)
            #self.mainbox.Add(btn)
            #vbox2.Add(btn,1,wx.ALIGN_RIGHT, 20) 
            #self.SetSizer(linebox)
            i+=1
        for j in range(len(btn)):
            linebox.append(wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL))
            linebox[j].Add(btn[j], 1, wx.CENTER)
            vbox2.Add(linebox[j], (0,int(j)), (1,1), 1, wx.CENTER)
        parent.SetSizer(vbox2)

    def onClick(self, event, link):
        webbrowser.open(link)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = window(None, "MarkIt")
    app.MainLoop()
```

`

The current problem is when I click on an element of the ListBox it creates all the buttons at the same position, no matter the sizer, unless I specify the exact position of the button (which would be inconvenient later down the line). The function that creates the buttons is this one:

```
    def onListBox(self, event, parent):
    category = event.GetEventObject().GetStringSelection() 
    query = "SELECT book_name, link FROM bookmarks WHERE category=\'"+category+"\'"
    data = self.dbase.execute(query) 
    #book_name = name of the bookmarks; link = eventual link of bookmark
    i=0
    vbox2=wx.GridBagSizer()
    btn=[]
    linebox=[]
    print('a')
    for row in data:
        #row[0] = book_name
        #row[1] = link
        btn.append(wx.Button(parent,-1,label=row[0]))
        #self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,lambda event:self.onClick(event, row[1]), btn)
        #self.mainbox.Add(btn)
        #vbox2.Add(btn,1,wx.ALIGN_RIGHT, 20) 
        #self.SetSizer(linebox)
        i+=1
    for j in range(len(btn)):
        linebox.append(wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL))
        linebox[j].Add(btn[j], 1, wx.CENTER)
        vbox2.Add(linebox[j], (0,int(j)), (1,1), 1, wx.CENTER)
    parent.SetSizer(vbox2)
```

Thanks for your help and time!

Comment: you need to call `.Layout()` (and maybe `.Fit()`)

Comment: I thought I already did that, but tried it again, just to make sure, and now it appears to work, thank you!